# Centos7_Jenkins_Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, centos7

`Chromedriver` is not working when i run in `jenkins`.

`Error in jenkins:org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running)`

**Local** 
Chrome Driver: 2.43.600210 
Chrome version 74.0.3729.169

**Jenkins_Run on centos7**
Chromium 78.0.3904.108
version: Google Chrome 79.0.3945.88
ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.16
location is /usr/bin/google-chrome
location /usr/bin/chromedriver
location chromium is under /usr/bin/chromium-browser
In Jenkins server we do have google chrome and google chrome stable

This is my code in eclipse

```
`
```

public class Driver {

private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();
/*
 * protected ExtentReports extentReport; private ExtentTest testCase;
 */

/** Name of the test case. */
private String testName;

/** Name of the test defined in the TestNG file. */
private String testArea;

/** Email IDs parsed from Jenkins */
private String allEmailIDs;

/** browser being tested; either defined in Variables file or Jenkins. */
private String browsername;
/**
 * Browser to be used for running the scripts; either defined in Variables file
 * or Jenkins.
 */
private String browser;

/** Opearting system from Bamboo */
private String operatingSystem;

Map<String, Object> chromeOptions;
private ChromeOptions chromeProfile;

private static ThreadLocal<EventFiringWebDriver> eventFiringWebDriver = new ThreadLocal<EventFiringWebDriver>();

/**
 * Browser capabilities being used. For list of capabilities available, please
 * visit:
 * http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities.html
 */
private DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

private ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

/*
 * *************************** Elements related to WCC+WCS
 **************************/
private String language;
/**
 * Type of the device being tested; either defined in Variables file or Jenkins.
 */
private String deviceType = "Desktop";
private String OS = "Centos7";
private String emailId;

/**
 * Environment being tested; either defined in Variables file or Jenkins.
 */
private String environment;
// public static final String environment = "stage";

public Driver(String testName, String testArea) throws MalformedURLException {
    // Set variables
    this.testName = testName;
    this.testArea = testArea;

    // Create driver
    createDriver();
}


/**
 * Create Driver
 */
private void createDriver() {


    if (Variables.isIE) {

        // Set IE Driver path
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "src/main/resources/IEDriverServer.exe");

        // Initialize IE driver
        Driver.driver.set(new InternetExplorerDriver());

        // Maximize window
        Driver.driver.get().manage().window().maximize();
    }

    else {
        // New file to load chrome driver
        File chromeDriver;

        try {


            chromeDriver = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources/chromedriver.exe");

            // Set chrome properties
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriver.getAbsolutePath());

            // Initialize chrome options
            this.chromeProfile = new ChromeOptions();
            options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
            // Initialize chrome options
            chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            Driver.driver.set(new ChromeDriver(chromeProfile));
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e) {

            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model
            options.addArguments("start-maximized"); // open Browser in maximized mode
            options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
            options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
            options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
            options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems


            chromeDriver = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources/chromedriver79");
            if (!chromeDriver.canExecute())
                chromeDriver.setExecutable(true);
            // Set chrome properties
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriver.getAbsolutePath());

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.setBinary("/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable");

            /*// Initialize chrome options
            this.chromeProfile = new ChromeOptions();
            options.setBinary("/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable");
            options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
            // Initialize chrome options
            chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            System.out.println("Running on Linux machine");
            Driver.driver.set(new ChromeDriver(chromeProfile));
            Driver.driver.set(new ChromeDriver());
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);*/


            // Initialize chrome options
            this.chromeProfile = new ChromeOptions();

            // Initialize chrome options
            chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            // Get extension set capabilities
            chromeProfile.addArguments("test-type");
            capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

            chromeProfile.addArguments("--user-agent=Moose and Seagull Unit Tests");
            chromeProfile.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeProfile);
            Driver.driver.set(new ChromeDriver(chromeProfile));

        }
        // Maximize window
        Driver.driver.get().manage().window().maximize();

        eventFiringWebDriver.set(new EventFiringWebDriver(driver.get()));
        EventHandler eventHandler = new EventHandler(getTestName());
        eventFiringWebDriver.get().register(eventHandler);
        //capabilities.setCapability("screen-resolution", "1280x1024");

    }
}

public EventFiringWebDriver getDriver() {
    return eventFiringWebDriver.get();
}

public static void setDriver(ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver) {
    Driver.driver = driver;
}

public String getTestName() {
    return testName;
}

public String getTestArea() {
    return testArea;
}

public String getDeviceType() {
    return deviceType;
}

public void setDeviceType(String deviceType) {
    this.deviceType = deviceType;
}

public String getBrowser() {
    return browser;
}

public void setBrowser(String browser) {
    this.browser = browser;
}

public String getBrowsername() {
    return browsername;
}

public void setBrowsername(String browsername) {
    this.browsername = browsername;
}

public String getLanguage() {
    return language;
}

public void setLanguage(String language) {
    this.language = language;
}

public void setTestArea(String testArea) {
    this.testArea = testArea;
}

public void setTestName(String testName) {
    this.testName = testName;
}

public void loggerInfo(ExtentTest logger, String status) {
    logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, status);
}

public void loggerPass(ExtentTest logger, String status) {
    logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, status);
}

}
`

Comment: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t

Comment: That's not helpful

Comment: Those didn't solved my issue @DebanjanB

Comment: @OMS Can you update the question with what exactly didn't work from the duplicate targets?

Comment: Locally its working fine. coming to jenkins which work's on centos7 getting this issue and my chrome driver and chrome browser versions are same. why am i getting this issue.@DebanjanB

Comment: ( I edit my question. Please check it once)@DebanjanB